# Problem with appending to bash arrays

Tags: arrays, git, bash

I'm trying to create an alias that will get all "Modified" files and run the php syntax check on them...

```
function gitphpcheck () {

    filearray=()

    git diff --name-status | while read line; do 

        if [[ $line =~ ^M ]]
        then
            filename="`echo $line | awk '{ print $2 }'`"
            echo "$filename" # correct output
            filearray+=($filename)
        fi
    done

    echo "--------------FILES"
    echo ${filearray[@]}

    # will do php check here, but echo of array is blank

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Wrikken says, the while body runs in a subshell, so all changes to the filearray array will disappear when the subshell ends. A couple of different solutions come to mind:

[Process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) (less readable but does not require a subshell)

```
while read line; do 
  :
done < <(git diff --name-status)
echo "${filearray[@]}"
```

Use the modified variable in the subshell using [command grouping](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping)

```
git diff --name-status | {
  while read line; do
    :
  done
  echo "${filearray[@]}"
}
# filearray is empty here
```

Comment: thank you for the solutions, just want to make sure that second `<` in the first solution is correct?

Comment: it is correct. process substitution (the "<()" syntax) essentially makes a pipeline look like a file. then the first "<" is the redirection to pass the contents to the while loop.

Answer (score 2):

You've piped `|` things to while, which is essentially another process, so the filearray variable is a different one (not the same scope).

Comment: Couldn't remember that fast (don't do a lot of bash), and by the time I got the solution, it's essentially glenn's 1st answer I could come up with.